# Default params for typescript generics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

Say I have

```
const myFunc = <T, > (data: T) => {
  return data?.map((d) => ({name: d.name})
}
```

Ts throws an error saying: `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'`, which makes sense so I can fix it with

```
const myFunc = <T extends {name: string}> (data: T) => {
  return data?.map((d) => ({name: d.name})
}
```

but the problem is that because I wanted `T` to be generic if I then call this function with

`myFunc(x: number)`

I get an error saying the types do not match, but I want it to match the type I pass in?

I should make something else clear I have a react component that has a prop called `myFunc` and the `myFunc` I've defined below is the default prop but a user could pass their own in

Comment: If you use an element of `data` as having a `name` wouldn't passing in `number` be a runtime error? It's not clear to me what code would run without errors, but which TS doesn't compile

Comment: Have you tried `<T extends {name: any}>`?

Answer (score 0):

Well by extending the type like that, the type needs to be an object that contains a name.

So try this

```
const myFunc = <Type extends {name: string} | number> (data: Type) => {
  return data?.map((d) => ({name: d.name})
}
```

(T i deprecated, so using Type instead)

Comment: "(T is deprecated, so using Type instead)" <-- deprecated by whom? Where do you get that from?

Comment: @jcalz maybe not deprecated, but the old documentation uses <T>, the new uses <Type>. 
new: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html
old: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html